# In neural networks, do the weights of bias terms get updated in backpropagation?

Tags: neural-network

In neural networks, I am trying to code it out, but got stuck on one part. Do the weights of bias terms get updated in backpropagation? I am following the algorithm here http://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/ and they seem to not update it, and they chose some arbitrary values for bias term weights. Does that mean the outputs of bias terms are 1, and its weights should not change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally: yes, the bias weights should be updated and included in training just as any other weight in the NN (also in backpropagation).

In the example you've posted, the bias `b1` is added to both neurons the hidden layer, and bias `b2` to both neutrons in the output layer

```
Hidden layer:
    h1 = i1*w1 + i2*w2 + 1*b1
    h2 = i1*w3 + i2*w4 + 1*b1

Output layer:
    o1 = h1*w5 + h2*w6 + 1*b2
    o2 = i2*w7 + h2*w8 + 1*b2
```

With initial, and in this example, fixed, biases

```
b1 = 0.35
b2 = 0.60
```

This means that the biases for hidden neutrons is always exactly 0.35, and for output neutrons exactly 0.60. This, however, is not usual practice, as you want to train your NN to find "good" biases just as much you want it to train to find good weights.

Note also, in the comments of the link you provided, that another user has asked why biases are not changed, and the author has replied, quote:

> "Hey, in the tutorials I went through they didn’t update the bias which
> is why I didn’t include it here."

This lack of a specific "why" possibly implies that the author of this example/tutorial is, however well-versed, no expert at the subject of NN, so you shouldn't put to much weight (no pun intended...) into the fast that the biases are not changed in this specific example.

---

If you really want to dig into a sound and thorough covering of NN in the context of back propagation, I would rather recommend you Michael Nielsen excellent book on NN and deep learning, specifically for this subject, Chapter 2. Note that the bias weights, here, are treated just as weights for neuron-neuron data transfer.

- http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html

Michael is a Google Researcher with numerous publicised articles in the subject of advanced NN and deep learning.

> At the heart of backpropagation is an expression for the partial
> derivative ∂C/∂w of the cost function C with respect to any weight w
> (or bias b) in the network. The expression tells us **how quickly the
> cost changes when we change the weights and biases.**

Comment: If I wanted to update the bias weights, how do I do it since there is no input to bias neurons?

Comment: Recall that in it's simplest form, the weights in a NN can be generalised as the specific data held by the chromosomes in the genetic algorithm used to train the NN. Hence, for this purpose, the bias weights are implicitly tested --- just as neuron-neuron weights --- by which chromosomes that give good fit w.r.t. test data. The evolutionary aspect of machine learning and genetic algorithm means we don't have to fiddle with details such as explicit feedback to specific weights (including bias weights). If you have the time, I recommend you Michaels book that I've linked to above.

Comment: Hey since you mentioned the michael I am asking you this one. He asks us to prove that change in cost wrt bias is equal to error.(Chapter 2 BP3) Will you please ask a question and answer yourself and comment the link here

Comment: @MadhusoodanP no, I will not solve this question for you. Is this homework? This is a programming help forum, not a free-solution-supplier forum (we do this for free). The laziness of asking me to even write the question for you is ... Nonetheless, you could attempt to ask this question on mathoverflow, including _your own attempt_.

Comment: @dfri Oh sorry but this not a homework problem. I am learning ANNs for my project and sorry for laziness. :)